# How to delete a large image from my LibreOffice doc?

Tags: openoffice, libreoffice-writer

I'm using LibreOffice Writer 5.4.5.1 (x64); I added a very large image (81 MB) to a doc (which already has several images, but none that large).

The document keeps going into "Not Responding" mode, and won't allow me to even get to the image so I can delete it. When I scroll *almost* to it, the doc freezes up.

How can I delete this image or otherwise fix the doc (odt file)?

Comment: Try making a copy of the document and changing the extension to .zip. Open this with an archive manager and remove the file or replace it with a smaller version. Return the odt extension and see if it works correctly.

Comment: It may be worth your time to copy the sections before the problem image to another doc, then copy the sections after, and continue working with the new doc.  Not elegant, but takes the least time.

Comment: Another thing to try is converting your odt file online to something like .CSV or other spreadsheeting format that does not support images. This should hopefully result in your image coming through as unrecognisable code that you can highlight and delete. Or at the very least give you access to the important data so you can copy/paste into a new file.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make a copy of the file (in case the below procedure fails on your document). I tested this on a real ODT file and works perfectly.

1. Rename the file extension of your copy file from odt to zip
2. Open with zip explorer (e.g. 7zip)
3. Navigate to folder Pictures
4. Delete the 8.1Mb image
5. Save the modified zip
6. Rename extension back to odt

The document should open as expected with an empty frame in the place of the big image saying "Read-Error". Delete the empty frame.

Answer (score 2):

What worked for me is saving the document in Microsoft Word format:

`Menu File -> Save As -> Word 2007-2019 (.docx)`

Then when I deleted the image, it didn't crash or freeze.

Optionally, when you're done, you can save it back to .odt format.

**WARNING**: during the conversion to .docx, some embedded object might be lost, for instance all my PDFs where turned into images. Anyway, this workaround might work if you don't have complex objects in your file.